# How can I center images pasted on email body and the greeting too?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

I copy different ranges of an Excel sheet and paste as an image in an email body.

I want to paste these images centered on the email.

```vb
Sub SendEmail()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olInsp As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim strGreeting As String

    strGreeting = "Dear Someone," & vbNewLine

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With olEmail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
        .Display

        .To = "Someone@tester.com"
        .Subject = "Report"

        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor

        wdDoc.Range.InsertBefore strGreeting

        wdDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf

        Range("B1:O56").Copy
        PasteAtEnd wdDoc

        wdDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf

        Range("B57:O111").Copy
        PasteAtEnd wdDoc
        
        wdDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf

        Range("B112:O172").Copy
        PasteAtEnd wdDoc

    End With

End Sub

'paste from clipboard to the end of the document
Sub PasteAtEnd(doc As Word.Document)
    With doc
        .Content.Select
        .Application.Selection.Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
        .Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What has this to do with Excel, for which you've added a tag?

Comment: Im using vba to copy different ranges as images and copy on an email body, thats why i tagged with excel... Im sorry if its not related

Answer (score 0):

In Word you can `center-align` paragraphs. For example:

```
For Each oILShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    oILShp.Select
    Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to center all the images and the greeting using the code below:

Set wdRange = wdDoc.Range(0, wdDoc.Characters.Count)

```
    wdRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    
    For i = 1 To wdRange.Tables.Count
        wdRange.Tables(i).Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
    Next i
```

Thanks!